# How can I lock orientation in OpenPlug (/flex)?

Tags: xcode, apache-flex, orientation, openplug

I'm writing program with Flex using OpenPlug. I'm having difficulties locking the devices orientation. From Project Properties I can find OpenPlug Studio Targeted Devices and their options. For iOS there is options to support (or not) different orientations and for Android / Symbian there is none.

Even if I select to support only "portrait" orientation with iOS, in emulator screen is not locked. I can't try it in real device, because I'm not able to generate XCode. There's another problem. I have selected to generate XCode, I've selected Apple - iPhone as device and I have selected target folder. When I click build-button, nothing happens..?

Any info regarding either one problem will be appreciated! :)

Comment: I replaced the open tag w/ openplug as I suspect that is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Not shure if this is still relevant - in OpenPlug Studio, you right-click on the project and choose "Properties". You then choose "OpenPlug Studio targeted Devices" on the left side in order to get the list of devices. You now click the button "Edit by Platform" on the upper right corner. This will render you a list of settings you can make. Among others, there are items "iPhone Support Landscape Left Orientation", "iPhone Support Landscape Portrait Orientation" and so on. Setting these should do the job of locking the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what OpenPlug is, but it looks like an IDE, but I'm not sure.  Frankly, it shouldn't matter.  If you have a Flex project, you should have an application descriptor file (an xml under the source directory).  Under that, there should be an 2 tags that you should be interested in:

```
<aspectRatio><!-- set portrait or landscape here --></aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```